# Select multiple ranges and paste one at time

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste

I'm really a begginer in the VBA and I'm trying to copy a serie of ranges and need to paste one at time (to the offset row work).

This image is what I have:
[image: This image is what I have]

And this image is what I want:
[image: and this image is what I want]

To do this i thinking in copy based on range only the odd ranges and paste in "F" column and copy only the even ranges and paste in "N" column.

At the moment, I have this code. I'ts work very well but i have 20 odd ranges and 20 even ranges. I need a symple way to put these 20 repetition

```
        Range("A3:G7").Copy
        Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Range("A15:G19").Copy
        Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Range("A27:G31").Copy
        Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

together (here i just show 3 repetition of the code).

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Car").Activate
    Range("F2:AA250").Delete
    Sheets("Summary").Activate

            Range("A3:G7").Copy
            Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range("A15:G19").Copy
            Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range("A27:G31").Copy
            Worksheets("Car").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range("F2").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't repeat the code 20 times (this would be a bad practice). Use a loop instead: `For i = 1 To 20` and use [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to get from your first range offset to the others.

Comment: If `xlPasteAll`, why `PasteSpecial` and not `Paste`? The ranges are identic. You must copy it and change the number in a simple iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I haven't tested it so would be surprised if it works first time!

It does rely on the top right cell having something in it. When it doesn't the loop will stop. A For-Next loop would be better if you know in advance how many copies you'll need.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, n As Long: n = 1

With Worksheets("Summary")
    Set r = .Range("A3:G7")
    Do Until IsEmpty(r.Cells(1, r.Columns.Count))
        r.Copy Worksheets("Car").Range("F" & n)
        r.Offset(r.Rows.Count + 1).Copy Worksheets("Car").Range("N" & n)
        Set r = r.Offset((r.Rows.Count + 1) * 2)
        n = n + r.Rows.Count + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method, please. It is enough to have only your first range. The code alternatively copy the range in its appropriate position, according to the iteration number (odd or even). You can make much more iterations, only changing the iterations number (`howMany`):

```
Sub CopyRange_()
Dim sh As Worksheet, nextRow As Long, howMany As Long
Dim rng As Range, i As Long, No As Long
Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set rng = sh.Range("A3:L8"): nextRow = rng.Cells(1, 1).Row
No = 2: howMany = 20
rng.Copy

 For i = 1 To howMany - 1
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        sh.Range("A" & nextRow).Select: sh.Paste
        sh.Range("L" & nextRow).value = No: No = No + 1
    Else
        sh.Range("N" & nextRow).Select: sh.Paste
        sh.Range("Y" & nextRow).value = No: No = No + 1
        nextRow = nextRow + rng.Rows.Count
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

If you will need more rows, it is enough to choose an appropriated range, instead of "A3:L8". "A3:L10", for instance...